# awk output into specified number of columns

Tags: unix

EDIT: I can get all my desired values from the command:

```
awk '/Value/{print $4}' *.log > ofile.csv
```

This makes a .csv file with a single column with hundreds of values. I would like to separate these values into a specified number of columns, i.e. instead of having values 1-1000 in a single column, I could specify that I want 100 columns and then my .csv file would have the first column be 1-10, 2nd column be 11-20... 100th column be 991-1000.

Previously, I was using the `pr` command to do this, but it doesn't work when the number of columns I want is too high (>36 in my experience).

```
awk '/Value/{print $4}' *.log | pr -112s',' > ofile.csv
```

the `pr` command gives the following message:
`pr: page width too narrow`

Is there an alternative to this command that I can use, that won't restrict the amount of comma delimiters in a row of data?

Comment: Please post sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

If your values are always the same length, you can use `column`:

```
$ seq 100 200 | column --columns 400 | column --table --output-separator "," 
100,103,106,109,112,115,118,121,124,127,130,133,136,139,142,145,148,151,154,157,160,163,166,169,172,175,178,181,184,187,190,193,196,199
101,104,107,110,113,116,119,122,125,128,131,134,137,140,143,146,149,152,155,158,161,164,167,170,173,176,179,182,185,188,191,194,197,200
102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147,150,153,156,159,162,165,168,171,174,177,180,183,186,189,192,195,198,
```

The `--columns` control the number of columns, but in my example, `400` is the number of characters, not the number of columns.

If your values are not the same character length, you will find spaces inserted where the values have a different width.